# Do not recreate fragment after screen rotation, because it is created by LiveData observer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I track my app state in ViewModel and it's livedata. 
E.g. clicking on button changes the state and via livedata it creates a fragment and inflates it into the view.

```
viewModel.panel.observe(this) { panel -> 
    if (panel != null) {
        val fragment = MyPanelFragment().apply {
            arguments = // set somehow based on panel
        }
        childFragmentManager.commit {
            replace(R.id..., fragment)
        }
    } else {
        childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id...)?.let { fragment ->
            childFragmentManager.commit {
                remove(fragment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After screen rotation, the fragment is recreated two times:

1. By receiving "current state" from viewModel and (re)createing the fragment in observer.
2. By framework, because it's state is saved in Bundle. (+-)

What is to correct approach to solve this?

1. Disable recreating by framework (e.g. storing fragments state). But how?
2. Somehow drop first observe from livedata when activity is recreated. But how? (Yes, I can use some mutating variable, but it quite smells)

Comment: guess the trick is to not use LiveData to broadcast events that are one-off actions

Comment: Use a PublishSubject (from rxjava) or use [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) instead of your regular livedata `panel`

Comment: Thank for suggestions. After thinking this through, I came to conclusion:
- the view model property is correctly a state, e.g. not something like openPanel; so the single live event or PublishSubject is not correct;
- the view implementation is somehow transactional, so it is the responsibility of view not to recreate, when state is already fulfilled.